# How do i exclude unmodified files in maven checkstyle?

Tags: maven-3, checkstyle

I would like to use http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/ as part of a project build with an intent to fail the build on a violation. However, since some of the projects already exist and it contains a lot of existing code, i would prefer to customize the checks in a way that it is only applies to modified files (svn/git) and not the whole project. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a pre-commit hook on your repository to run checkstyle on file add/update,that way there is no need to fail the build, you can just block the commit. Refer to this use case: http://saturnnetwork.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/ultimate-architecture-enforcement-prevent-code-violations-at-code-commit-time/